# The decorator keeps throwing out "address must be a string"

Tags: nestjs

I'm writing code that registers a company or user, the difference is that the company has an address. I added a check for this property inside the controller. The problem is that if the property is there, then everything works, a new company is created, but if the property is not there, then the error `“address must be a string”` is written.

My Controller

```
    @Post('register')
        async register(@Body() dto: RegisterDto) {
            try {
                if (!dto.address) {
                    return await this.rmqService.send<AccountRegister.Request,    AccountRegister.Response>(
                        AccountRegister.topic,
                        dto,
                    );
                }
                return await this.rmqService.send<CompanyRegister.Request, CompanyRegister.Response>(
                    CompanyRegister.topic,
                    dto,
                );
            } catch (error) {
                if (error instanceof Error) {
                    throw new UnauthorizedException(error.message);
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to fix this by changing the decorators in the DTO for the address property but that didn't help.

My DTO

```
    export class RegisterDto {
        @IsEmail()
        email: string;
    
        @IsString()
        password: string;
    
        @IsString()
        number: string;
    
        @IsString()
        displayName: string;
    
        @IsString()
        @IsOptional()
        address?: string;
    }
```

My Request for user(not work)

```
    {
        "email": "a@a.ru",
        "password": "Hello World",
        "number": "12345678912",
        "displayName": "My Name"
    }
```

My Request for Company(work)

```
    {
        "email": "a@a.ru",
        "password": "Hello World",
        "number": "12345678912",
        "displayName": "My Name",
        "address": "New York"
    }
```

Comment: did you save your code :D?

Comment: @HaiAlison Yes, do you think I forgot?

Comment: so I think you should npm run build to re-build your code and then start it